# use a php SESSION string for d3.js tree JSON instead of .json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a nice working d3.js-tree as long as I use JSON-data from a .json-file.
But now, I want to give the opportunity to the customer to individualize the tree in some ways. For me it seems logical therefore, to use the SESSION to hold the respective JSON-String and to load this SESSION-variable into my tree-script.

Therefore, I use window.SESSION like this and parse the string to JSON.

```
 var treedatajson = JSON.parse(window.SESSION.filtered_tree);
```

But this seems not to work. The string must be ok, as I can copy it into a file and load a functioning tree with the following code:

```
 var treedatajson = "filtered_tree.json";
```

Why doesn't JSON.parse() work that way? And what can I do to get this running?

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Let me know if there is something unclear or you need more code for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like in  `var treedatajson = "filtered_tree.json";` when it worked you were passing in the filename, and in `var treedatajson = JSON.parse(window.SESSION.filtered_tree);` you were passing in the json data.  What is the next line where you use `treedatajson`?  You are probably looking for a filename there instead of the parsed data.

... or maybe you should create a php endpoint that serves the session data as json... something like

```
<?php
// filtered-tree.php
session_start()
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_SESSION['TREE']); // or whatever the key is
```

and then in js

```
var treedatajson = "filtered-tree.php";
```

Comment: Sorry, something went wrong... Here again:
it is the tree after this example: https://gist.github.com/robschmuecker/7880033

And the next line is the function for creating the tree and its routines: 
treeJSON = d3.json(treedatajson, function(error, treeData) {

To be honest, I don't know whether it only refers to the file/path or directly uses the json.... I'll try to change things to check that....

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764698/loading-d3-js-data-from-a-simple-json-string

Comment: you're my hero :D
I overwrite the treeData within the function with my parsed JSON-string, which works very well. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: ok, your idea with the .php probably also works... but I think in my case, a solution without an aditional file would be better.